# Notation in expectation of $N(a,1)$ distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am looking for some clarification in the notation used here:

Let $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $a\in\mathbb R$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
E[\exp(aX)]&=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)\exp(ax)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-a)^2+\frac{1}{2}a^2\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}a^2\right)\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-a)^2\right)\,\mathrm dx=\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}a^2\right)
\end{align*}
$$
because
$$
x\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-a)^2\right)
$$
is the density of an $\mathcal{N}(a,1)$ distribution.

What does the maps to mean here explicitly? I am just confused at this last line. I understand this as meaning $x$ is drawn from a $N(a,1)$ distribution. Is that somewhat correct?

Comment: In the fourth expression the integrand is recognized as a PDF so that the integral takes value $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a mathematical trick. They did some simple algebraic manipulation to reduce the problem to the integral of a pdf. Then they used the fact that all pdfs integrate to 1.

In general, the pdf of a $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution is given by,

$$f_{\mu,\sigma}(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$

Setting $\mu = a$ and $\sigma^2 = 1$ yields,

$$f_{a,1}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-(x-a)^2}{2}\right).$$

So the map you were asking about is just the mapping $x \mapsto f_{a,1}(x)$. Because the integral of any pdf is 1,

$$E[\exp(aX)] = \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}a^2\right)\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-a)^2\right)\,dx = \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}a^2\right)\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{a,1}(x)\,dx = \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}a^2\right).$$